# ASM - Intel to AT&T

Tags: assembly, x86

I've to convert this Intel ASM code into AT&T ASM:

```
    mov al, byte ptr [n]
    mov byte ptr [genint+1], al
    jmp genint
genint:
    int 0
```

I was not able to do it, but here my try:

```
    movb (n), %al
    movb %al, (genint+1)
    jmp genint
genint:
    int 0
```

Any help please ? 
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int 0` should be `int $0`. Otherwise it should be fine, even though you have a few harmless extra parentheses. Note that if you are using gnu assembler, that can be switched to intel syntax using `.intel_syntax noprefix`.

```
    movb n, %al
    movb %al, genint+1
    jmp genint
genint:
    int $0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still can compile it. I Get this error:  /tmp/ccmT496y.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccmT496y.s:81: Error: bad register name `%almovb %al'

Comment: That just means you messed up the end of the line. Maybe using dos/mac encoding?

Comment: I'm using GCC (this is inline asm). I've edited the comment with the error message! Still many thanks!

Comment: In inline asm, you have to add line breaks manually, as `\n` into the string.